# Fetch subquery value from cursor to parameter in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, subquery, fetch

I have below query to select the count of subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (select crs_cust.CUSTOMER_ID, 
subset.NEW_REFERENCE_ID FROM CRS_CUSTOMERS crs_cust INNER JOIN DAY0_SUBSET subset ON crs_cust.CUSTOMER_ID=subset.CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID);
```

Above query is executed from a cursor in PL/SQL, how can I fetch columns from subquery (`CUSTOMER_ID` and `NEW_REFERENCE_ID`) into respective parameter?

The cursor is expected to have multiple records.Similiar like the following:

```
p_Count := SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DAY0_SUBSET;
OPEN c1; 
LOOP
FETCH c1 into p_Current_CustomerId,p_New_Cust_Ref_ID; -->query from cursor's subquery
EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
EXIT WHEN (c1%ROWCOUNT <> p_Count);

FOR i IN c1 LOOP
<do manipulation of subquery values>
END LOOP;
END IF;
CLOSE c1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns of sub queries are not projected so you can't reference them. If you want the `CUSTOMER_ID` and `NEW_REFERENCE_ID` in your program you will have to select them in the top level `SELECT` clause.
The easiest answer to your solution is to just open a cursor for your
subquery itself, for eample:

```
BEGIN
  FOR cur IN (SELECT crs_cust.CUSTOMER_ID, subset.NEW_REFERENCE_ID
               FROM CRS_CUSTOMERS crs_cust
                INNER JOIN DAY0_SUBSET subset ON 
                  crs_cust.CUSTOMER_ID=subset.CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID)
  LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cur.customer_id || ', ' || cur.new_reference_id);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: thanks, another way i am thinking is to remove SELECT COUNT(*) FROM, just open a cursor for the subquery. And use c1%ROWCOUNT to reference the count of records fetched by cursor.

Comment: Yes, you can do that as well. What is it that you are trying to do? Sounds like you want to have both, the `CUSTOMER_ID` and `NEW_REFERENCE_ID` as well as the total count of the rows? If so, than you can do that exactly the way you said.